# md-select not selected when the ng-value is an object

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
  <md-select name='services' ng-model="vm.service.service_group" placeholder="Select a  Group"  required>
      <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in vm.service_group" ng-selected="true" >{{ opt.name }}</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

I have this select option in my form.This will not get selected on edit the object.How can make the ng-model to be selected on edit?

Thanks

Comment: I have recreated a plunker for you, can you check if this helps you with your issue, if not send a modified plunkr with the problem, the code provided is not enough

Comment: can you share the link? please!

Comment: sorry forgot to include the link :p here it is https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/t8gz1sk6/68/

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I can get selected using a value of the object, the problem is it's not getting selected when the value is an object.I updated my scenario on the jsfiddle.

Comment: a new link will be created, you need an account there, share me the new link

Comment: see the link, https://jsfiddle.net/nizarucsc/t8gz1sk6/70/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151573/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-mohamed-nizar).

Comment: I was able to hide the label when nothing is selected but it still does not look proper, https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/t8gz1sk6/72/ but it seems that this is the only proper answer https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/t8gz1sk6/74/ is  this acceptable?

Comment: Here what I expected ,https://jsfiddle.net/nizarucsc/t8gz1sk6/75/

Comment: ok cool, glad you resolved it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I got to resolve it.I added `ng-selected="opt.code==vm.service.service_group.code"` to check the selected values.

```
<md-select name='services' ng-model="vm.service.service_group" placeholder="Select a  Group"  required>
     <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in vm.service_group" ng-selected="opt.code==vm.service.service_group.code" >{{ opt.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Hope this will help some one

Comment: You have to do this because of equality check for objects. If you use the same instance from vm.service_group of selected object in ng-model (instead of creating a new one) it will work as expected.